Access a Method in a PL/SQL Collection of Objects Using a Pipelined function
I created an object type that contains attributes and methods. I access the object with a pipelined function that returns a collection of that object. This that works file, except I can not access any of the methods of the object returned in the collection. I can see the attributes fine.
Is it possible to access a method of a object when using a pipelined function?
I am not sure if I misunderstand how pipelined functions work, or I should be using a different methodology.
I am doing this in an attempt to speed up a long-running and memory-intensive process. The goal is using pipelining in parallel to speed everything up and learn some new stuff along the way.
--object
TYPE schema1.cool_object FORCE AS OBJECT
(
-- Attributes
att_pid NUMBER,
att_some_number number,
--method
method function some_number_doubled Return Number.
)
--nested table type of cool_object
TYPE schema1.cool_object_ns IS TABLE OF schema1.cool_object;

--Function takes (weak) ref cursor returns nested table of the object type
function f_pipeline(p_rows SYS_REFCURSOR) Return schema1.cool_object_ns

--Call to pipeline function
SELECT * FROM TABLE (schema1.package1.f_pipeline (CURSOR ( Select pid, some_number from person_table)));

This returns an object with attributes att_pid and att_some_number accessible in the object but, not the methods.

Did you create the types as schema objects?

Try
SELECT t.*, t.some_number_doubled() FROM TABLE (schema1.package1.f_pipeline (CURSOR ( Select pid, some_number from person_table))) t;


Thank you for you quick response. That did it.


Create the types in the SQL scope and not as part of a PL/SQL package.
The function in the object should be a MEMBER FUNCTION and not a METHOD FUNCTION.
The function in the object (probably) needs a SELF argument.
The type needs a body.
The function is not pipelined as you do not use the PIPELINED keyword in the signature.
To use the member function in the query you need to give the row an alias and then use alias.some_number_doubled().

CREATE TABLE person_table (pid, some_number) AS
SELECT LEVEL, LEVEL + 39 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;

CREATE TYPE cool_object AS OBJECT (
  -- Attributes
  att_pid NUMBER,
  att_some_number number,
  --method
  MEMBER FUNCTION some_number_doubled (
    self cool_object
  ) RETURN NUMBER
);

CREATE TYPE BODY cool_object
AS 
  MEMBER FUNCTION some_number_doubled (
    self cool_object
  ) Return Number
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN 2 * self.att_some_number;
  END;
END;
/

CREATE TYPE cool_object_ns IS TABLE OF cool_object;

This function could be in a package if you want (but the previous object cannot):
--Function takes (weak) ref cursor returns nested table of the object type
CREATE FUNCTION f_pipeline(
  p_rows SYS_REFCURSOR
) RETURN cool_object_ns PIPELINED
IS
  v_pid         PERSON_TABLE.PID%TYPE;
  v_some_number PERSON_TABLE.SOME_NUMBER%TYPE;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    FETCH p_rows INTO v_pid, v_some_number;
    EXIT WHEN p_rows%NOTFOUND;
    PIPE ROW(cool_object(v_pid, v_some_number));
  END LOOP;
END;
/

Then you can call it:
--Call to pipeline function
SELECT t.*,
       t.some_number_doubled()
FROM   TABLE(
         f_pipeline(
           CURSOR(SELECT pid, some_number from person_table)
         )
       ) t;

Which outputs:



ATT_PID
ATT_SOME_NUMBER
T.SOME_NUMBER_DOUBLED()




1
40
80


2
41
82


3
42
84


4
43
86


5
44
88




But I'm not sure why you need the cursor or the pipelined function as you can simplify it to:
SELECT t.co.att_pid AS att_pid,
       t.co.att_some_number AS att_some_number,
       t.co.some_number_doubled() AS some_number_doubled
FROM   (
  SELECT cool_object(pid, some_number) AS co
  FROM   Person_table
) t;

fiddle

You are correct about using 'member' in my example. I just mistyped my example. As for why I am using a pipeline is to decrease memory usage. Thank you for you detailed explanation. I very much appreciate it.
